# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 400 - Bad status line "Expected dot" with HTTP/2 Response

Tags: python-3.x, http, client, http2, aiohttp

I am using the aiohttp library in Python to send a POST request to a server. However, I am encountering a ClientResponseError with a 400 status, and the error message seems to indicate a problem with the status line in an HTTP/2 response:

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 400, message='Bad status line "Expected dot:\\n\\n b'HTTP/2 200 OK\\\\r'\\n ^"', url=URL('https://example.com/api/response')
```

**Here is a simplified version of my code:**

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

url = 'https://example.com/api/response'

def get_random_user_agent():
    return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'

def default_headers():
    return {
        'User-Agent': get_random_user_agent(),
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
    }

headers = default_headers()
headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

payload = {"key": "value"}

async def fetch(url, headers, payload):
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ssl=False)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        async with session.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                return await response.text()
            else:
                print(f"Error: {response.status}, {await response.text()}")
                return None

asyncio.run(fetch(url, headers, payload))
```

**Attempts to resolve:**

I have tried forcing **aiohttp** to use HTTP/1.1 by setting **force_close=True** and **ssl=False** on the **TCPConnector**, but the issue persists. I am considering switching to another library like **httpx**, but I would prefer to understand and resolve this issue with **aiohttp** if possible.

**Questions:**

Why am I receiving a **400 Bad Request** response with an “Expected dot” error message in the status line, even though the server seems to be responding with **HTTP/2 200 OK**?
Is this issue related to a misconfiguration on the server, or is it something I can address in my client code?
Are there any workarounds or fixes available within the **aiohttp** library to handle such cases, or should I consider using a different HTTP library?

Comment: What happens when you make same request with `cURL`? How do you know server is responding with 200?

Comment: I've ruled out server-side issues as the root cause. I used cURL with the --insecure option to bypass SSL certificate verification and successfully received a 200 OK response. Thus, it seems that the problem originates from aiohttp or the way I'm using it. I'm still exploring potential solutions or workarounds within the aiohttp framework and am open to any suggestions or insights.

Comment: $ curl -k -i -X POST https://example.com/api/response -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" -d '{"key":"value"}'

HTTP/2 200
server: nginx
date: Thu, 21 Sep 2023 12:01:37 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 0
x-powered-by: PHP/5.4.45
x-powered-by: PleskLin

Comment: Well the problem with this is, we have no way of cross checking. Your code looks fine and without knowing server response etc, it is hard to tell what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of interoperability issues here.

The first is the server sending `HTTP/2` as the HTTP version; the server should send `HTTP/2.0`.
This is specified in RFC 9113 [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9113.html#name-response-pseudo-header-fiel), where it is specified that the version is "2.0" not "2".
This is further confirmed by RFC 9110 [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-protocol-version), where it is specified that the version number consists of two decimal digits separated by a ".".

The form "HTTP/2" is a colloquial form used in text and verbal communication to indicate version 2 of the HTTP protocol.

Having said that, I'd say that the client library is way too strict at parsing the protocol version, considering that other clients have no problems with it, and also considering that the protocol version is only transmitted in HTTP/1.x.
In HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 the version it is not transmitted at all, making this information somehow of lesser importance because it is synthetically reconstructed in more recent version of HTTP anyway, rather than being parsed from the protocol.

Lastly, it is legal to reply with `HTTP/2.0` to an `HTTP/1.1` request?

[RFC 7230, section 2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230.html#section-2.6) hints that the version in the response advertises the server capabilities, but only within the same major number.
Therefore, a server may send `HTTP/1.1` in response to an `HTTP/1.0` request, but should not send `HTTP/2.0` in response to an `HTTP/1.1` request.

Comment: aiohttp uses llhttp for parsing, which doesn't allow a version number without a dot. aiohttp also doesn't support HTTP/2 currently, so the message would fail anyway if it doesn't conform to HTTP/1.1. Seems like a fairly broken server..